# Вылетает Аndroid-приложение, не могу получить ссылку на ArrayList

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Есть такой код:

```
public ListView listView;
    public ArrayList<ToDoDocument> listDocument; //aarray list объекта ToDoDocument
    public ToDoAdapter adapter; // Adapter

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listDocument = ((AppContext) getApplicationContext()).getListDocuments(); // получаю listDocument Из класса AppContext;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);  
    }

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    adapter = new ToDoAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDocument);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Код класса Appcontext:

```
public class AppContext extends Application{

    private ArrayList<ToDoDocument> listDocuments = new ArrayList<ToDoDocument>();
    public ArrayList<ToDoDocument> getListDocuments() {
        return listDocuments;
    }

}
```

Так вот с таким кодом запускаю, вылетает приложение Android и не запускается.

Если я меняю одну строчку

```
listDocument = ((AppContext) getApplicationContext()).getListDocuments();
```

на

```
listDocument =  new ArrayList<ToDoDocument>();
```

работает нормально.

Почему вылетает, почему я не могу получить ссылку на ArrayList в другом классе?

P.S. Выдает такую ошибку:

> Java.lang.ClassException:
> android.app.Application cannot be cast
> to
> kamnedsoft.example.todoapplication.AppContenxt.

Я так понял, что-то связано с приведением типов.

Comment: @duddeniska насколько понимаю, getApplicationContext() возвращает android.app.Application, который не может быть приведен к ...AppContext. Вы уверены, что не переопределяли getApplicationContext() и что AppContext наследуется от Application?

p.s. андро**и**д

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listDocument = ((AppContext) getApplication()).getListDocuments(); // получаю listDocument Из класса AppContext;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_todo);  
    }
```

Т.е. использовать `getApplication()` вместо `getApplicationContext()`.

И еще нужно убедиться, что в манифесте указан класс для Application.

```
<application
        android:name=".AppContext"/>
```

Comment: В манифесте не было прописано, спасибо, помогли!